# Detect text file encoding

Tags: c++, qt, character-encoding

In my program I load plain text files supplied by the user:

```
QFile file(fileName);
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream stream(&file);
const QString &text = stream.readAll();
```

This works fine when the files are UTF-8 encoded, but some users try to import Windows-1252 encoded files, and if they have words with special characters (for example "è" in "boutonnière"), those will show incorrectly.

Is there a way to detect the encoding, or at least distinguish between UTF-8 (possibly without BOM), and Windows-1252, without asking the user to tell me the encoding?

Comment: I'm afraid not, really.  The curse of plain text files.  A quick google backs that up:  http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/12619

Comment: Try and decode the text as UTF-8. If it fails, it isn't UTF-8.

Comment: How do I know that it fails?

Comment: @Mattsjo Yes, I read that before posting my question. How about the second part - just distinguishing between UTF-8 and Windows-1252? Would that be possible? Btw I know Notepad++ does it, but probably they write a lot of code for it.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you know what UTF-8 is? You can tell whether a byte sequence is a valid UTF-8 sequence or not.

Comment: I mean using a standard Qt function to get a QString from a byte array, which might or might not have valid UTF-8 text, how do I know that it failed? For example [QString::fromUtf8()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#fromUtf8) will not return success or failure, instead it will silently replace any invalid sequences.

Comment: What Kerrek SB means is that some files are _certainly_ not UTF-8. Then again, you'd still have issues telling ISO-8859-1 and -15 apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that auto-detecting the encoding is impossible for the general case.

However, there is a workaround to at least fall back to the system locale if the text is not valid UTF-8/UTF-16/UTF-32 text. It uses `QTextCodec::codecForUtfText()`, which tries to decode a byte array using UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32, and returns the supplied default codec if it fails.

Code to do it:

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForUtfText(byteArray, QTextCodec::codecForName("System"));
const QString &text = codec->toUnicode(byteArray);
```

**Update**

The above code will not detect UTF-8 without BOM, however, as codecForUtfText() relies on the BOM markers. To detect UTF-8 without BOM, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18228382/492336.

Answer (score 4):

This trick works for me, at least so far. This method does not require BOM to work:

```
    QTextCodec::ConverterState state;
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
    const QByteArray data(readSource());
    const QString text = codec->toUnicode(data.constData(), data.size(), &state);
    if (state.invalidChars > 0)
    {
        // Not a UTF-8 text - using system default locale
        QTextCodec * codec = QTextCodec::codecForLocale();
        if (!codec)
           return;

        ui->textBrowser->setPlainText(codec->toUnicode(readSource()));
    }
    else
    {
        ui->textBrowser->setPlainText(text);
    }
```