# Check if UTF-8 string is valid in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8

In Qt, is there a way to check if a byte array is a valid UTF-8 sequence?

It seems that [QString::fromUtf8()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#fromUtf8) silently suppresses or replaces invalid sequences, without notifying the caller that there were any. This is from its documentation:

> However, invalid sequences are possible with
>   UTF-8 and, if any such are found, they will be replaced with one or
>   more "replacement characters", or suppressed.

Comment: I suspect that to check the validity of a UTF8 string, you'd need to use a Unicode library.

Comment: I found this code snippet: [https://github.com/JulienPalard/is_utf8]. It could be useful.

Comment: The link gives me "Page not found"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try with [QTextCodec::toUnicode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html#toUnicode-2) and passing a [ConverterState](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec-converterstate.html) instance. ConverterState has members like `invalidChars`. They are not documented via doxygen though, but I assume them to be public API, as they are mentioned in the QTextCodec documentation.

Sample code:

```
QTextCodec::ConverterState state;
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
const QString text = codec->toUnicode(byteArray.constData(), byteArray.size(), &state);
if (state.invalidChars > 0) {
    qDebug() << "Not a valid UTF-8 sequence.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that put me in the right direction. Turns out there's an even simpler way using [QTextCodec::codecForUtfText()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html#codecForUtfText), which allows you to specify a default codec if no UTF encoding is suitable for the text. I specified [QTextCodec::codecForLocale()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html#setCodecForLocale) as the default codec.

Comment: This isn't working as I expected. If there are embedded zeros in the byteArray, the validity is only checked up to the first zero. I'd expect to continue validating until the end, why is otherwise the size provided? I know I could checked before if the byte array contains '\0' but it would mean less performance. Should this be considered a bug in Qt?

Comment: @Gneuromante: I don't think so, as byte value 0 is a null-terminator for UTF-8 encoded string. Nowhere do the docs say that the data can be interpreted as a set of strings separated with 0-terminators. I think you should split the data into individual strings yourself if you know it can contain more than one.

Answer (score 2):

The `ConverterState` way, which has already been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18228382/2660408) by Frank Osterfeld, works even if the text hasn't got a "BOM (Byte Order Mark)" (*).

(*) Unlike `QTextCodec::codecForUtfText()`, which needs a BOM in the text in order to know that it's in Utf-8.