# Checking if the content language uses the right to left direction?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, right-to-left

Is there a built-in method in Qt or another way to check if the content language uses the Right-to-Left direction?

```
QFile fileHandle("c:/file.txt");
if(!fileHandle.open(QFile::ReadOnly|QFile::Text))
    return;
QTextStream fileContent(&fileHandle);
fileContent.setCodec("UTF-8");
fileContent.setGenerateByteOrderMark(false);
ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(fileContent.readAll());
fileHandle.close();
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but in string and character literals it's only the *back* slash (\\) that needs to be escaped not the forward slash (`/`).

Comment: In the string `"c://file.txt"` you use two forward slashes, that's not needed. `"c:/file.txt"` should work fine.

Comment: I have put that text just for example. anyway, I thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't work too much with right-to-left languages, but hope these suggestions can help you:

- If you know your content is in UNICODE you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18253554/1485885) (use `QTextCodec::codecForUtfText`) to detect exact encoding. Then, classify the symbols to detect the dominant subset (left-to-right: English, Cyrillic..., right-to-left: Arabic, Hebrew...), probably a histogram will be enough. You could use a language detection framework instead, but I think you only need the *type* of language, not the language itself (which is by far more complex).
- Search for the [*right-to-left mark* (RLM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) (a non-printed character commonly used to indicate bi-directional text). If you create the content you can add the RLM at the beginning of the file (the [opposite (LRM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) also exists).